# Converting a multivariate equation into a Binary Matrix in Python or Sagemath

Tags: python-3.x, aes, symbolic-math, sage

i have a multivariate quadratic sum

> x0 + x1*y1 + x0*y0 + y1

the variables in this case are

> {x0,x1,y0,y1,x0*y0,x1*y1,x0*y1,x1*y0}

So giving the previous quadratic sum as an input , how can I take back the matrix [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0] according to the previous basis.

I'm working in SageMath.

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Give it a shot and then show us what you have done and we can help from there.

Comment: I solved the problem. I m working on algebraic attacks on AES and having created the finite field GF(2) equations of a small scale variant, I wanted to have the binary matrix so as to perform relinearization, XL , XSL etc. I figured it out how to convert the equation into matrix with the funtion .set(0) of Sagemath. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @VasilisTz could you post a minimum working example of how you got it working as an answer so others know question is answered and can benefit from it too.